# How to capture the network traffic using python

Tags: python, network-traffic

I am using python and attempting to scrape the HTTP(s) traffic between my computer and a site, which would include all incoming and outgoing requests,responses, such as images and external calls, etc.

I have attempted to find the network traffic within my `hit_site` function, but I'm not finding the information.

```
hit_site("http://www.google.com")

def hit_site(url):
    print url
    r = requests.get(url,stream = True)
    print r.headers
    print r.encoding
    print r.status_code
    print r.json()
    print requests.get(url,stream=True)
    print r.request.headers
    print r.response.headers
    for line in r.iter_lines():
        print line
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    return soup
```

An example of the type of information that I would like to capture is the following (I used fiddler2 to get this information. All of this and more came from visiting groupon.com):

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
6   200 HTTP    www.groupon.com /   23,236  private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate text/html; charset=utf-8    chrome:6080         
7   200 HTTP    www.groupon.com /homepage-assets/styles-6fca4e9f48.css  6,766   public, max-age=31369910    text/css; charset=UTF-8 chrome:6080         
8   200 HTTP    Tunnel to   img.grouponcdn.com:443  0           chrome:6080         
9   200 HTTP    img.grouponcdn.com  /deal/gsPCLbbqioFVfvjT3qbBZo/The-Omni-Mount-Washington-Resort_01-960x582/v1/c550x332.jpg    94,555  public, max-age=315279127; Expires: Fri, 18 Oct 2024 22:20:20 GMT   image/jpeg  chrome:6080         
10  200 HTTP    img.grouponcdn.com  /deal/d5YmjhxUBi2mgfCMoriV/pE-700x420/v1/c220x134.jpg   17,832  public, max-age=298601213; Expires: Mon, 08 Apr 2024 21:35:06 GMT   image/jpeg  chrome:6080         
11  200 HTTP    www.groupon.com /homepage-assets/main-fcfaf867e3.js 9,604   public, max-age=31369913    application/javascript  chrome:6080         
12  200 HTTP    www.groupon.com /homepage-assets/locale.js?locale=en_US&country=US  1,507   public, max-age=994 application/javascript  chrome:6080         
13  200 HTTP    www.groupon.com /tracky 3       application/octet-stream    chrome:6080         
14  200 HTTP    www.groupon.com /cart/widget?consumerId=b577c9c2-4f07-11e4-8305-0025906127fe    17  private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate application/json; charset=utf-8 chrome:6080         
15  200 HTTP    www.googletagmanager.com    /gtm.js?id=GTM-B76Z 39,061  private, max-age=911; Expires: Wed, 22 Oct 2014 20:48:14 GMT    text/javascript; charset=UTF-8  chrome:6080
```

I would greatly appreciate **any ideas as to how capture the network traffic using python.**

Comment: @CharlesDuffy do you have any suggestions?

Comment: See `urllib2.build_opener(...)` and `HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)`.

Comment: "How to capture the network traffic using python" (as added by a very recent edit) is a fine question. "Use Requests (HTTP for Humans) to capture all HTTP(s) traffic between my computer and site in Python" is not. Why don't you update the title, if the former is what you meant to ask?

Comment: Look here: http://www.binarytides.com/code-a-packet-sniffer-in-python-with-pcapy-extension/

Answer (score 10):

[dpkt](https://dpkt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is an extensive tool (written in Python) for parsing TCP traffic, which [includes support for decoding packets involved in the SSL handshake](https://dpkt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/api_auto.html#module-dpkt.ssl). Another tool for running and decoding captures from Python is [pypcapfile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypcapfile).

Note that for decoding SSL traffic *including data*, private keys need to be known. This is somewhat problematic for a third-party server you don't control such as Google, and significant effort is required to work around it. One such approach is to set up a proxy with a known private key to play man-in-the-middle (and install a self-signed CA into your local store to force the browser to accept it).