# How can I capture the URL of the devices connected to my Network

Tags: python, url, logging, squid

I need help, information, ideas, advice on how I can capture the URLs accessed by the devices connected to my Network. Below I explain the case.

I have a device that bridges devices (cell phones or computers) and the Internet, the operating system of this device is Ubuntu 18, this is configured (not by me so I can not give more details). What I was asked for is a solution, which allows you to create continuous logs of the pages visited by the connected users and the time they are on these pages. I was also asked that the devices that connect through my bridge have to be registered with a username and password. (As well as some free Internet points in several countries). Then this information will be used to give a report to the teacher. The point is that I tried with Squid-Proxy and it is not what I am looking for because for this to work I must configure the search engines of each device separately and as it is evident I cannot do this.

Beforehand thank you very much.

P.S. If the solution could be in Python it would be great.

Comment: This is the english language version of Stack Overflow, please write your question in English or you might want to try the spanish language Stack Overflow, https://es.stackoverflow.com/.

Esta es la versión en inglés de Stack Overflow. Por favor formula tu pregunta en inglés o quizá quieras intentar en Stack Overflow en Español: https://es.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: maybe you should use [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to register all network traffic on this device with Ubuntu 8 and later use this data to search urls.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/26516772/11392720
dpkt is an extensive tool (written in Python) for parsing TCP traffic, which includes support for decoding packets involved in the SSL handshake. Another tool for running and decoding captures from Python is pypcapfile.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will also forward the question on this link.

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance. :D